# Programação Concorrente x Paralela x Distribuída

Tags: paralelismo, ciência-da-computação, concorrência, sistemas-distribuídos

O que são, quais as características de cada uma?

Problemas que cada uma se propõe a resolver?

Principais diferença entre elas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A principal diferenças entre esses tipos de programas são as suas formas de execuções.

A **programação concorrente** é a mais comum, onde o programa é executado sequencialmente concorrendo pela disponibilidade do(s) processador(es) com os demais programas. Cada processador executa apenas uma linha de comando por vez, por isso a concorrência, e quem cuida dessa concorrência é o [Escalonador de Processos](http://ctd.ifsp.edu.br/~marcio.andrey/images/Escalonamento-Processos-IFSP.pdf) que escalona um novo processo a cada vez que um processo fica bloqueado, executa uma operação E/S <sup>[1]</sup> ou no término.

A maior desvantagem desse tipo de programação, é que qualquer ação que demanda algum tempo de processamento irá "travar o usuário" e ele não poderá realizar nenhuma outra ação até que a primeira termine.

A **programação paralela** também conhecida como **assíncrona** é também uma programação concorrente, porém com mais linhas de execuções, onde o programa é dividido em vários "sub-processos" conhecido como *Threads* que serão executados paralelamente com o processo pai. Essa forma de desenvolvimento é melhor aproveitada quando dispõe de dois ou mais núcleos de processamento.

O melhor exemplo de paralelismo é o navegador que você está utilizando agora, que provavelmente está com mais de uma aba aberta (na verdade eu não estudei os códigos dos navegadores) e provavelmente cada aba está sendo executada em uma ou mais *threads*, pois quando você abre uma nova aba, não precisa esperar o site terminar de carregar tudo, para poder mudar para outra aba.

[image: Threads]

Na ilustração um único processo contendo quatro *threads* em que cada uma "está sendo executada paralelamente" <sup>[2]</sup> em núcleos diferentes do processador.

Na **programação distribuída** o sistema é executado em vários ambientes interligados por uma rede (internet ou intranet). Esse tipo de sistema tem a vantagem de dispor de uma maior capacidade de processamento e consequentemente aguentar um número maior de usuários/requisições/processos.

Algumas desvantagens que devem ser muito bem tratadas na hora do planejamento de sistemas distribuídos são: Falhas na rede ou máquinas que podem comprometer o sistema; Devido o acoplamento ser feito via rede, sua comunicação pode ser lenta e/ou gerar um tráfego intenso na rede; Segurança dos dados, como o tráfego é feito via rede, não tratar a segurança do tráfego é um ponto fraco desse tipo de sistema.

Sobre a programação distribuída, o maior exemplo da atualidade são os mineradores de bitcoins. É impossível um computador comum ter todo poder de processamento necessário, então entra a programação distribuida "juntando" o processamento de todos os computadores integrados.

Material de Leitura:

- [Programação Distribuída](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~frank/INE5645/4.%20Programacao%20Distribuida.pdf),
- [Programação Concorrente](http://www.cic.unb.br/~alchieri/disciplinas/graduacao/pc/introducao.pdf),
- [Programação Paralela](http://www.devmedia.com.br/programacao-paralela/21405)

<sub>1: Operação de Entrada e/ou Saída.

2: Em um ambiente real, milhares de instruções são executadas por segundo, então cada *thread* pode ser executada paralelamente com outros processos, em vez do processo pai ou suas *threads* irmãs.</sub>