# Usando threads em classes

Tags: c++, thread, multithreading

Olá, eu tenho um problema quanto ao uso de threads. Uma vez que eu uso o mingw para compilar os meus projetos, e  este `header` não está implementado, eu uso [este](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7tq215ttsgw2l9/thread.h?dl=0) `header` para compilar os meus projetos. No entanto, estou a ter algumas dificuldades quanto ao uso de threads em classes.

```
class classe {
public:
    std::thread *THREAD = NULL;
    void Func() {}
    classe() {
        THREAD = new std::thread(Func);
    }
    ~classe() {
        delete THREAD;
    }
};
```

Este código acima não compila e agradecia que me explicassem se não compila por causa da biblioteca que estou a usar ou se é um comportamento padrão desta funcionalidade e como eu poderia adaptar o código acima para que funcionasse.
P.S. Eu não coloquei a tag de memória dinâmica, pois acredito que essa parte está correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E ae cara!
vou destacar um ponto no seu código que deve estar causando o erro de compilação.

```
delete[] THREAD;
```

este delete é para deletar um array, veja que `THREAD` é declarada como `std::thread *THREAD = NULL`. o delete[] seria utilizado se fosse declarado um array de thread como `std::thread *THREADS[]`,
o correto seria utilizar `delete THREAD`.

caso tenha dúvidas sobre `delete` e `delete[]` acesse este [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/).

> e como eu poderia adaptar o código acima para que funcionasse.

eu implementaria da seguinte forma (você pode modificar para atender suas necessidades)

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

class classe
{
public:
classe() : m_thread(nullptr){}

void start()
{
  m_running.store(true);
  m_thread.reset(new std::thread(&classe::worker, this));
}

// thread que invoca stop() será bloqueada até que worker tenha completado
void stop()
{
  m_running.store(false);
  m_thread->join(); //não esqueça dessa parte =) (se seu worker estiver em foreground)
}
private:

void worker()
{
  while(m_running.load())
  {
    // realize algum processo
  }
}

std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread;
std::atomic<bool> m_running;
};
```

**DÚVIDAS**
como solicitado pelo autor da pergunta, irei dar uma breve explicação sobre alguns pontos do código.

> o que é std::unique_ptr?

contido no header `<memory>` o `std::unique_ptr` (antigo _auto_ptr) é acompanhado por mais dois "coleguinhas", são eles, `std::shared_ptr` e `std::weak_reference` e esses caras são conhecidos como ***smart* *pointers*** (ponteiros inteligentes).

a ideia por trás do nome bonito é que o programador não precise se preocupar em desalocar memória dinâmica.

exemplo de `std::shared_ptr`

```
using SPtr = std::shared_ptr<int>;

{

  SPtr original(new int(10));

  original.use_count(); // retorna 1

  {

    SPtr segundo = original;

    original.use_count(); // retorna 2

    // "original" e "segundo" compartilham o mesmo ponteiro para um inteiro;

  } // fim do escopo, "segundo" será destruído na stack

  original.use_count(); // retorna 1

} // fim do escopo, original será destruido e ficando com use_count() igual a 0 e com isso o pointero será deletado automaticamente;
```

claro que há mais benefícios em utiliza-los, como utilizar `shared_ptr` para um object que será compartilhado entre threads.
aconselho que estude sobre smart pointers.

Link em português: [Smart Pointer - Introdução](http://www.pontov.com.br/site/cpp/43-smart-pointers/52-smart-pointer-introducao)

> o que é atomic?

de forma sucinta serve para sincronizar threads ao acessar uma variável deste tipo.
caso não faça sentido, recomendo que estude sobre `thread`, `mutex` e data races.

Leia antes de iniciar os estudos: [Programação Concorrente x Paralela x Distribuída](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75727/programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-concorrente-x-paralela-x-distribu%C3%ADda)

espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado, funciona! Eu tenho uma outra dúvida, como eu adapto o código para a thread execute apenas 1 vez?

Comment: no método privado worker(); você pode remover o loop (while(true){ }).

Comment: Só mais uma coisa, estive a analisar o código, mas não consigo perceber como é que funciona. Podia fazer-me o favor de mo explicar?

Comment: Parabéns por ter interesse para aprender como o código funciona, poucos o fazem.
em qual ponto você está com dificuldade para entender?
Destaque e tentarei explicar da melhor forma possível.

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pela disponibilidade! Tenho dificuldade a entender a parte do `unique_ptr` e o `atomic`.

Comment: editei a minha resposta de forma que explique um pouco mais sobre o código.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento e pelo seu tempo disponibilizado!